# Using R, how to roll a number of dice and discard the lowest-rolling die?

Tags: r, probability, dice

Using R, I would like to help friends visualize probabilities associated with dice for games. However, I don't know how to write code in R that would allow me to do the following:

- Roll a number of dice (ex: 4 six-sided dice), discard the die with the lowest roll, and add the rest.

It feels like it should be fairly simple to do, but I haven't yet figured out a way to do it.

Comment: @r2evans, `sort(...)[-1]` is an elegant way to write it, but it's apparently an order of magnitude slower than `x<-...; x[-which.min(x)]`! That's surprising to me.

Comment: Makes sense to me. To find the min you don't need to do all the extra work to put everything in order. Just cycle through once to keep track of the lowest value you've observed so far and the corresponding index. If you find a lower value keep track of that instead. But for all the non min values you don't need to figure out what order they go in. Saves loads of time.

Answer (score 2):

```r
sum(sort(sample(6, size = 4, replace = TRUE), partial = 1)[-1])
```

To see what this is doing, we'll use a static seed and walk through it all.

```r
### four six-sided dice
set.seed(6); sample(6, size = 4, replace = TRUE)
# [1] 4 6 2 3

### sort just the minimum to the front
set.seed(6); sort(sample(6, size = 4, replace = TRUE), partial = 1)
# [1] 2 3 6 4

### remove the minimum at the front
set.seed(6); sort(sample(6, size = 4, replace = TRUE), partial = 1)[-1]
# [1] 3 6 4

set.seed(6); sum(sort(sample(6, size = 4, replace = TRUE), partial = 1)[-1])
# [1] 13
```

(`sort(..., partial=1)` sorts until a minimum is found and places it at the beginning of the vector; no sorting is done after that. While not required for the problem, without it unneeded sorting is done. Take it or leave it :-)

**Edit**

As suggested by Brian, apparently sharing my eagerness to optimize early:

```r
x <- sample(6, size=4, replace=TRUE)
sum(x[-which.min(x)])
```

is about 8-10x faster than `sort(...)` and 4-5x faster than `sort(..., partial=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is about visualizing the probabilities, I took a different approach.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

dice_roller <- function(n = 4, sides = 6, num_rolls = 1000) {
  tibble(
    rolls = rerun(num_rolls, sample.int(sides, n, replace = TRUE)),
    lowest = map_dbl(rolls, ~min(.x)),
    kept = map(rolls, ~.x[-which.min(.x)]),
    sum = map_dbl(kept, ~sum(.x))
  )
}
```

This function takes 3 arguments: number of dice, type of dice, and number of rolls.

- Then for every rolls, it makes a sample of integers based on the number of sides, and the size of the sample is the number of dice.
- Then it maps over every roll and finds the minimum value, just to record it for displaying.
- Then it maps over every roll and says: give me all of this vector, except the minimum value's index.
- Then it maps over every vector of kept values, and records the sum.
- And returns it all in a dataframe for future investigation.

So if we run this function (and a little tidying code for display):

```r
dice_roller() %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(rolls, kept), 
    ~map_chr(., paste, collapse = ",")
    )
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 4
#>    rolls   lowest kept    sum
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 1,5,3,6      1 5,3,6    14
#>  2 2,5,3,5      2 5,3,5    13
#>  3 6,2,2,1      1 6,2,2    10
#>  4 1,1,5,4      1 1,5,4    10
#>  5 2,4,5,2      2 4,5,2    11
#>  6 1,1,3,1      1 1,3,1     5
#>  7 1,4,3,2      1 4,3,2     9
#>  8 1,3,4,3      1 3,4,3    10
#>  9 6,3,3,5      3 6,3,5    14
#> 10 3,4,6,5      3 4,6,5    15
#> # … with 990 more rows
```

Handy, so let's look at the probabilities!

```r
ggplot(dice_roller(), aes(sum)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# Fewer dice per roll makes the distribution more skewed
ggplot(dice_roller(n = 3), aes(sum)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# More dice approaches a "normal" distribution of integers
ggplot(dice_roller(n = 10), aes(sum)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(dice_roller(num_rolls = 100000), aes(sum)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>